# What happened to the Teva after the flood?

Tags: tanach, parashat-noach, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

Is there any mention of this in any texts?

Side question: if the צהר was in fact a precious stone, what happened to that after the flood?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Searches_for_Noah%27s_Ark

Comment: @Ploni I think it's fair to ask about the fate of the Teiva and a component thereof in the same question. *Ab initio*, I'd expect them to be in the same place, unless some other treasure-hunter already got there and made off with the Tzohar!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Yalkut Shimoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Shimoni) to Ester (1056) states the God preserved the ark (or at least part of it) as a remembrance of the deluge for future generations, and Haman's son sent him a 50 cubit beam from it which he used for the gallows intended for Mordekhai:

> יעשו עץ גבוה חמשים אמה והיה המן חוזר ומבקש קורה של חמשים אמה ולא מצאה, אלא קורה שהיתה בתוך ביתו לפי שהיה בנו פרשנדתא הגמון בקרדוניא **ונטל נסר אחד מתיבותא של נח שהיה ארכו של נסר חמשים אמה שעשה הקדוש ברוך הוא זכרון בעולם שידעו דורות העולם שבא מבול לעולם** ... **עד עכשו היא עומדת שיהו הדורות מתנים בשבחו של בורא עולם**
>
> Haman tried to find a 50 cubit beam, but couldn't find one...His son Parshandata was a minister of [Kardunia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardunia%C5%A1) and he took a 50 cubit beam from Noah's ark, which God preserved as a reminder in the world that future generations should know that a deluge came to the world...It stood until now so that [later] generations should praise God.

By indicating that the beams of the ark were taken from Kardunia, the Midrash indicates that the ark (or at least part of it) remained on Mt. Arrarat, for Targum Onkelos (Genesis 8:4) render "the mountains of Arrarat" as "the mountains of Kardu", (see also Targum Pseudo-Jonathan there).

A similar Midrash (cited in [Sanhedrin 96a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.96a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) portrays Sennacherib taking a beam from Noah’s ark, and making an idol from it:

> אזל אשכח דפא מתיבותא דנח אמר היינו אלהא רבא דשיזביה לנח
>
> He went and took a beam from Noah's ark and said this is the great God that saved Noah.

H/T @DoubleAA